# VB.NET: End of Statement error on IF statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have the following IF statement and I am getting an 'End of Statement' error under: not in ('Deferred','Rejected','Closed')

```
 If (temp_var_1 = temp_var_2) And temp_var_3 not in ("Deferred","Rejected","Closed") Then
```

If I put parentheses around temp_var_3 and the right most ')', under ***not*** I get: ')' expected

```
If (temp_var_1 = temp_var_2) And (temp_var_3 not in ("Deferred","Rejected","Closed")) Then
```

A few notes:

- All temp variables are strings.
- It works in MS SQL: temp_var_3 not in ('Deferred','Rejected','Closed')

Comment: replace single quote with double quote. The title of your question suggests you're missing `End If`, but I can't assert if that's the case with the code you added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If (temp_var_1 = temp_var_2) AndAlso (Not {"Deferred", "Rejected", "Closed"}.Contains(temp_var_3)) Then
```

Also, if you put **Option Strict On** at the top of the file it will help you find errors.

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning option strict on

Comment: @Andrew Morton Thanks!!! http://i290.photobucket.com/albums/ll253/jeremy__31/Open_Online/Awesome_14.jpg

Comment: @Jeremy F. You're welcome. If it answers your question, please mark it as an answer.